# Moving domain/email from MS Exchange to GSuite

Tags: email, email-accounts, google-domains

I currently have a domain hosted by a company and an exchange email server and users use MS Outlook. I want to change over the domain from the current company to Google Domains and have the email through GSuite. How do I back up ALL emails ever received on each email to a .pst file to load into GSuite email? I know I can create the backup .pst file on a computer for emails on it, but will it pull all emails from server for backup even if they're 10 years old?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read through this documentation?  https://support.google.com/a/answer/180898?hl=en